# Sort columns of a dataframe by column name

Tags: r, sorting, dataset

This is possibly a simple question, but I do not know how to order columns alphabetically.

```
test = data.frame(C = c(0, 2, 4, 7, 8), A = c(4, 2, 4, 7, 8), B = c(1, 3, 8, 3, 2))

#   C A B
# 1 0 4 1
# 2 2 2 3
# 3 4 4 8
# 4 7 7 3
# 5 8 8 2
```

I like to order the columns by column names alphabetically, to achieve

```
#   A B C
# 1 4 1 0
# 2 2 3 2
# 3 4 8 4
# 4 7 3 7
# 5 8 2 8
```

For others I want my own defined order:

```
#   B A C
# 1 4 1 0
# 2 2 3 2
# 3 4 8 4
# 4 7 3 7
# 5 8 2 8
```

Please note that my datasets are huge, with 10000 variables. So the process needs to be more automated.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can use `order` on the `names`, and use that to order the columns when subsetting:

```
test[ , order(names(test))]
  A B C
1 4 1 0
2 2 3 2
3 4 8 4
4 7 3 7
5 8 2 8
```

For your own defined order, you will need to define your own mapping of the names to the ordering. This would depend on how you would like to do this, but swapping whatever function would to this with `order` above should give your desired output.

You may for example have a look at [Order a data frame's rows according to a target vector that specifies the desired order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977102/order-a-data-frames-rows-according-to-a-target-vector-that-specifies-the-desire), i.e. you can `match` your data frame `names` against a target vector containing the desired column order.

Comment: To elaborate,  test[,c(2,3,1)] or test[,c('A','B','C')]  will produce A,B,C column order.  The  "[" operator is very clever at figuring out what you want to do.

Comment: thank you, I figured out the second question with help provided; myorder = c("B", "A", "C"), test[,myorder]

Comment: Is there a way to sort the columns in a way I want (say C A B)?

Comment: You can take advantage of the fact that a data.frame is a list and make it simpler:: 

    `test[ order(names(test)) ]`

Comment: What is the difference between using `names()` vs `colnames()` here?

Comment: @naco None, read the source of `colnames`: it ends up calling `names` for a `data.frame`.

Comment: Is there way to make the ordering numerical? I have var names as "q" then a number 1 - 80 I need ordered and the ordering goes 1, 10, 11... so on which is wrong. I need 1,2 3...so on

Answer (score 49):

Here's the obligatory `dplyr` answer in case somebody wants to do this with the pipe.

```
test %>% 
    select(sort(names(.)))
```

Comment: For me this worked well since it's easy to select the variables I want first. Sticking to the original df:  `test%>%select(b,sort(names(.)))` will put it as "b,a,c"

Answer (score 17):

```
test = data.frame(C=c(0,2,4, 7, 8), A=c(4,2,4, 7, 8), B=c(1, 3, 8,3,2))
```

Using the simple following function replacement can be performed (but only if data frame does not have many columns):

```
test <- test[, c("A", "B", "C")]
```

for others:

```
test <- test[, c("B", "A", "C")]
```

Answer (score 11):

An alternative option is to use `str_sort()` from library **stringr**, with the argument `numeric = TRUE`. This will correctly order column that include numbers *not just alphabetically*:

`str_sort(c("V3", "V1", "V10"), numeric = TRUE)`

`# [1] V1 V3 V10`

Answer (score 8):

```
  test[,sort(names(test))]
```

sort on names of columns can work easily.

Answer (score 6):

If you only want one or more columns in the front and don't care about the order of the rest:

```
require(dplyr)
test %>%
  select(B, everything())
```

Answer (score 4):

So to have a specific column come first, then the rest alphabetically, I'd propose this solution:

```
test[, c("myFirstColumn", sort(setdiff(names(test), "myFirstColumn")))]
```

Comment: and if you want more than one column to be first, then what?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I found out to achieve a similar problem with my data set.

First, do what James mentioned above, i.e.

```
test[ , order(names(test))]
```

Second, use the everything() function in dplyr to move specific columns of interest (e.g., "D", "G", "K") at the beginning of the data frame, putting the alphabetically ordered columns after those ones.

```
select(test, D, G, K, everything())
```

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other syntax above but for learning - can you sort by column names?

```
sort(colnames(test[1:ncol(test)] ))
```

Comment: The `[1:ncol(test)]` isn't doing anything here, it's just a longer way to write `sort(colnames(test))`.

Answer (score 1):

another option is..

```
mtcars %>% dplyr::select(order(names(mtcars)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table` you can use the function `setcolorder`:

> setcolorder reorders the columns of data.table, by reference, to the
> new order provided.

Here a reproducible example:

```r
library(data.table)
test = data.table(C = c(0, 2, 4, 7, 8), A = c(4, 2, 4, 7, 8), B = c(1, 3, 8, 3, 2))
setcolorder(test, c(order(names(test))))
test
#>    A B C
#> 1: 4 1 0
#> 2: 2 3 2
#> 3: 4 8 4
#> 4: 7 3 7
#> 5: 8 2 8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>