# Order data frame rows according to vector with specific order

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

Is there an easier way to ensure that a data frame's rows are ordered according to a "target" vector as the one I implemented in the short example below?

```
df <- data.frame(name = letters[1:4], value = c(rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, 2)))

df
#   name value
# 1    a  TRUE
# 2    b  TRUE
# 3    c FALSE
# 4    d FALSE

target <- c("b", "c", "a", "d")
```

This somehow seems to be a bit too "complicated" to get the job done:

```
idx <- sapply(target, function(x) {
    which(df$name == x)
})
df <- df[idx,]
rownames(df) <- NULL

df 
#   name value
# 1    b  TRUE
# 2    c FALSE
# 3    a  TRUE
# 4    d FALSE
```

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Try `match`:

```
df <- data.frame(name=letters[1:4], value=c(rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, 2)))
target <- c("b", "c", "a", "d")
df[match(target, df$name),]

  name value
2    b  TRUE
3    c FALSE
1    a  TRUE
4    d FALSE
```

It will work as long as your `target` contains exactly the same elements as `df$name`, and neither contain duplicate values.

From `?match`:

```
match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument 
in its second.
```

Therefore `match` finds the row numbers that matches `target`'s elements, and then we return `df` in that order.

Comment: Great, that's more like it and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot

Comment: one question, what if the column that I would like to match has repeat values? like `b,c,a,d,b,c,a,d`. I tried `match` but it does not work well.

Comment: @Yulong: I'd think you'd have to explicitly make sure that duplicates are removed prior to firing `match()`. What comes to mind is `duplicated()`, `unique()` or some other custom routine that "keeps" the desired elements while throwing away the others. HTH

Comment: @Edward it's a nice solution. However, it also changes the indices. How can I also keep them in the ascending order(1, 2, 3, 4) ?

Comment: not sure it is the cleanest way, but with only "base" functions, this should work if you have duplicates in df:
`df <- data.frame(name=letters[c(1:4, 1:4)], value=c(rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, 2),rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, 2) ))


target <- c("b", "c", "a", "d")


df[order(unlist(sapply(df$name, function(x) which(target == x)))),] `

Answer (score 59):

We can adjust the factor levels based on `target` and use it in `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(factor(name, levels = target))

#  name value
#1    b  TRUE
#2    c FALSE
#3    a  TRUE
#4    d FALSE
```

Or `order` it and use it in `slice`

```
df %>% slice(order(factor(name, levels = target)))
```

Comment: The best solution IMO

Comment: The best and the simplest solutions for me.

Comment: Applies well, only if the "target" vector contains the same elements as the "name" vector; else, order breaks up.

Answer (score 30):

I prefer to use `***_join`  in `dplyr` whenever I need to match data. One possible try for this

```
left_join(data.frame(name=target),df,by="name")
```

Note that the input for `***_join` require tbls or data.frame

Comment: Yeah, the *_join functions in `dplyr` are really nice. End up using these a lot by now as well

Comment: In this case, recommend declaring target order as a tibble, to avoid data.frame() conversion to factors. `target <- tibble(name = c("b", "c", "a", "d"))`

Comment: And with pipe syntax: `df %>% right_join(tibble(name = target), by = "name")`

Comment: Please, be careful. This is not anymore possible since dplyr 1.0.0. A breaking change. See [changelog](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#breaking-changes)

Comment: df %>% right_join(target, ., by = "name")

Answer (score 19):

This method is a bit different, it provided me with a bit more flexibility than the previous answer.
By making it into an ordered factor, you can use it nicely in `arrange` and such. I used reorder.factor from the `gdata` package.

```
df <- data.frame(name=letters[1:4], value=c(rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, 2)))
target <- c("b", "c", "a", "d")

require(gdata)
df$name <- reorder.factor(df$name, new.order=target)
```

Next, use the fact that it is now ordered:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(name)
    name value
1    b  TRUE
2    c FALSE
3    a  TRUE
4    d FALSE
```

If you want to go back to the original (alphabetic) ordering, just use `as.character()` to get it back to the original state.

Comment: Does anyone know a data.table version of this?

Comment: @Reilstein `setDT(df)[ , name := factor(name, levels = target)]`. Then see the two `data.table` answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns/)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use any libraries and you have reoccurrences in your data, you can use `which` with `sapply` as well.

```
new_order <- sapply(target, function(x,df){which(df$name == x)}, df=df)
df        <- df[new_order,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar system for the situation where you have a variable you want to sort by, initially, but then you want to sort by a secondary variable according to the order that this secondary variable first appears in the initial sort.

In the function below, the initial sort variable is called `order_by` and the secondary variable is called `order_along` - as in "order by this variable along its initial order".

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df <- structure(
  list(
    msoa11hclnm = c(
      "Bewbush", "Tilgate", "Felpham",
      "Selsey", "Brunswick", "Ratton", "Ore", "Polegate", "Mile Oak",
      "Upperton", "Arundel", "Kemptown"
    ),
    lad20nm = c(
      "Crawley", "Crawley",
      "Arun", "Chichester", "Brighton and Hove", "Eastbourne", "Hastings",
      "Wealden", "Brighton and Hove", "Eastbourne", "Arun", "Brighton and Hove"
    ),
    shape_area = c(
      1328821, 3089180, 3540014, 9738033, 448888, 10152663, 5517102,
      7036428, 5656430, 2653589, 72832514, 826151
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame"
)
```

this does not give me what I need:

```r
df %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(shape_area, lad20nm)
#>    msoa11hclnm           lad20nm shape_area
#> 1    Brunswick Brighton and Hove     448888
#> 2     Kemptown Brighton and Hove     826151
#> 3      Bewbush           Crawley    1328821
#> 4     Upperton        Eastbourne    2653589
#> 5      Tilgate           Crawley    3089180
#> 6      Felpham              Arun    3540014
#> 7          Ore          Hastings    5517102
#> 8     Mile Oak Brighton and Hove    5656430
#> 9     Polegate           Wealden    7036428
#> 10      Selsey        Chichester    9738033
#> 11      Ratton        Eastbourne   10152663
#> 12     Arundel              Arun   72832514
```

Here’s a function:

```r
order_along <- function(df, order_along, order_by) {
  cols <- colnames(df)
  
  df <- df %>%
    dplyr::arrange({{ order_by }})
  
  df %>% 
    dplyr::select({{ order_along }}) %>% 
    dplyr::distinct() %>% 
    dplyr::full_join(df) %>% 
    dplyr::select(dplyr::all_of(cols))
  
}

order_along(df, lad20nm, shape_area)
#> Joining, by = "lad20nm"
#>    msoa11hclnm           lad20nm shape_area
#> 1    Brunswick Brighton and Hove     448888
#> 2     Kemptown Brighton and Hove     826151
#> 3     Mile Oak Brighton and Hove    5656430
#> 4      Bewbush           Crawley    1328821
#> 5      Tilgate           Crawley    3089180
#> 6     Upperton        Eastbourne    2653589
#> 7       Ratton        Eastbourne   10152663
#> 8      Felpham              Arun    3540014
#> 9      Arundel              Arun   72832514
#> 10         Ore          Hastings    5517102
#> 11    Polegate           Wealden    7036428
#> 12      Selsey        Chichester    9738033
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: how to handle if I have 27 observations (A1 to A38) repeated several times (total rows 7938) and I would like to sort based on the same. target <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A18", "A24", "A25", "A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A30", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38")