# Reorder rows using custom order

Tags: r, dplyr

Given data:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(category=LETTERS[1:3], b=1:3)
DT
#    category b
# 1:        A 1
# 2:        B 2
# 3:        C 3
```

Using `dplyr`, how to rearrange rows to get specific order `c("C", "A", "B")` in `category`?

```
#    category b
# 1:        C 3
# 2:        A 1
# 3:        B 2
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

First, create a vector with the letters in the desired order. Then `match`* the vector with the variable to be sorted. `match` returns indices of (first) matches, which can be plugged into `slice`:

```
library(dplyr)

# create a vector with letters in the desired order
x <- c("C", "A", "B")

DT %>%
  slice(match(x, category))
#   category b
# 1        C 3
# 2        A 1
# 3        B 2
```

Another way would be to convert "category" to a `factor`, set `levels` to the desired order, and use `arrange`:

```
DT %>%
  mutate(category =  factor(category, levels = x)) %>%
  arrange(category)    
#   category b
# 1        C 3
# 2        A 1
# 3        B 2
```

*The `match` method is inspired by [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977102/order-a-data-frames-rows-according-to-a-target-vector-that-specifies-the-desire/11977256#11977256).

Comment: As mentioned in the inspiring answer, watch out for the effect of duplicates when using `match()`.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative could be the following, note that arrange can take a list of new indices.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(category = LETTERS[1:3], b = 1:3, stringsAsFactors = F)

# create a vector with letters in the desired order
x <- c("C", "A", "B")

df %>%
arrange(sapply(category, function(y) which(y == x))
```