# How to extract an unique element according a set of prefered conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, data-extraction

Taking the data-frame *df*, I would like to extract the **unique** *value* according to the following preferred conditions per each *Field*:

1- if **C1** exists, extract the respective value and ignore the others

2- if **C2** exists, extract the respective value and ignore the others

... and so on up to **C5**

data:

```
df <- data.frame (Field=rep(c("F1","F2","F3","F4","F5"),each=3),
              Cond=rep(c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5"),3),
              Value=c(1:15))
```

the desired *output*:

```
output <-  data.frame (F= c("F1","F2","F3","F4","F5"),
                   C= c("C1","C1","C2","C1","C3"),
                   Value= c(1,6,7,11,13))
```

(note1: the *values* were only set as such to a matter of exemplification, the *real data values* are not ordered)

(note2: The *real conditional* column is not ordered alphabetically at all. my though was to have something like, if A exists than chose "A value", otherwise pass to the next condition "if B exists ..." and so on)

Comment: Can one assume values in `C` are sorted?

Comment: @Roman, no ... the values were only set as such to a matter of exemplification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(Field, Cond), head(.SD, 1), by = Field]
#    Field Cond Value
#1:    F1   C1     1
#2:    F2   C1     6
#3:    F3   C2     7
#4:    F4   C1    11
#5:    F5   C3    13
```

Comment: yes it works indeed if "Cond" is to be sorted alphabetically. however if the "sort" column is not ordered alphabetically that example would not work.

Comment: @Rui  In that case, convert it to `factor` and specify the `levels` in the order you want  `order(Field, factor(Cond, levels = lvl))`

Answer (score 2):

If you can sort the data.frame before processing, this is fairly easy. Note that this works for this particular case. If your `Cond` values change, alphabetic sorting may go out the window.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame (Field=rep(c("F1","F2","F3","F4","F5"),each=3),
                  Cond=rep(c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5"),3),
                  Value=c(1:15))

df <- df[with(df, order(Field, Cond)), ]
res <- df %>%
  group_by(Field) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)

Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: Field [5]

   Field   Cond Value
  <fctr> <fctr> <int>
1     F1     C1     1
2     F2     C1     6
3     F3     C2     7
4     F4     C1    11
5     F5     C3    13
```

Here is another, more genereric way, of doing this. Order of sorting is defined in `so` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548495/reorder-rows-using-custom-order)). Notice how I mangled up the values for `Cond` to show that it's not being sorted alphabetically.

```
df <- data.frame (Field=rep(c("F1","F2","F3","F4","F5"),each=3),
                  Cond=rep(c("rg1","kl2","xy3","rq4","ab5"),3),
                  Value=c(1:15))

so <- c("rg1","kl2","xy3","rq4","ab5")

df %>%
  group_by(Field) %>%
  slice(match(so, Cond)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)

   Field   Cond Value
  <fctr> <fctr> <int>
1     F1    rg1     1
2     F2    rg1     6
3     F3    kl2     7
4     F4    rg1    11
5     F5    xy3    13
```

Comment: indeed you are right, I dint think that would be a problem. My "conditional" column is not ordered alphabetically at all.
my though was to have something like, if A exists than chose "A value", otherwise pass to the next condition "if B exists ..." and so on

Comment: @Rui I modified my answer and I think it should work for your general case now.