# Reordering rows in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to reorder rows in a dataframe based on a specific order. Here is a dummy dataframe (in the long format) that pretty much looks like my data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#data frame
MV<-c(rnorm(50,mean=10, sd=1),rnorm(50,mean=9, sd=1))
ML<-c(rnorm(50,mean=12, sd=1),rnorm(50,mean=10, sd=1))
NL<-c(rnorm(50,mean=10, sd=1),rnorm(50,mean=8,sd=1))
ID<-rep(1:50,1)
Type<-rep(c("BM","NBM"),times=1, each=50)
df<-data.frame(ID, Type, MV, ML, NL)

#Here is the dataframe:
df.gat<-gather(df, "Tests", "Value", 3:5)
```

My data is already in the long format to start with (df.gat). The code before that is just to get you a similar dataframe.

Basically, I'd like to have my data ordered in my dataframe in the following order: NL, MV, and ML

I have tried various methods such as the following [Reorder rows using custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548495/reorder-rows-using-custom-order) or [How does one reorder columns in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame) which are not very convenient considering the number of rows in my dataset.

The solution also needs to work if some participants didn't do all the tests.

Any solution?

Comment: how about `df[c("ID","Type","NL","MV","ML")]` or `df[,c(1,2,5,3,4)]`

Comment: Seems like you're talking about columns, not rows?

Comment: Yes I would like to reorder the rows based on the values in the a specific column.

Comment: @DanielO, my dataframe is in the long format to start with (df.gat). The code provided before is just get you a similar dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

In that case you could just tweak what I suggested above into:

```
df.gat[rev(order(df.gat$Tests)),]
```

which happens to do the trick for me here but not necessarily generically.
If you want something generic you could (re-)create (the/a) factor:

```
df.gat$tests2 <- factor(df.gat$Tests, levels=c(c('NL','MV','ML')))
df.gat[order(df.gat$tests2),]
```

which should give you the same ordering as above.

Comment: I think the `factor` approach is best - you wouldn't have to explicitly add another column if not required though, e.g.: - `df.gat[order(factor(df.gat$Tests, c("NL","MV","ML"))), ]`

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you simply want to reorder the columns of your dataframe. Why not do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#data frame
MV<-c(rnorm(50,mean=10, sd=1),rnorm(50,mean=9, sd=1))
ML<-c(rnorm(50,mean=12, sd=1),rnorm(50,mean=10, sd=1))
NL<-c(rnorm(50,mean=10, sd=1),rnorm(50,mean=8,sd=1))
ID<-rep(1:50,1)
Type<-rep(c("BM","NBM"),times=1, each=50)
df<-data.frame(ID, Type, MV, ML, NL)
df.gat<-gather(df, "Tests", "Value", 3:5)

df <- df %>% select(NL, MV, ML, everything())
```

Comment: Actually,  my data is already in the long format (e.g.: df.gat). The code provided before was just to build something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just placing multiple parameters in an order() call like so?

```
df[order(MV,ML,NL),]
```

Your df isn't the best demonstration of this as they're all decimals.
Here is a simpler alternative example using discrete values:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
   C1=sample(rep(c(10,20,30)   ,20)), 
   C2=sample(rep(c('A','B','C'),20)))
df2[order(df2$C1,df2$C2),]
```

I'm not sure why you'd need dplyr:gather() in your example if you're just working on reordering df, right?

Comment: I should have specified that my dataframe is in the long format to start with (df.gat). The code provided before are just to get a dataframe similar to the one I'm using.