# Order a dataframe based on the order of rownames in another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I am working with two dataframes. I want to reorder the rows of one dataframe so that it is identical to the order of the rows in the second dataframe.

I have one dataframe with counts and the other with metadata.
I need the same order to generate vectors of metadata for statistical comparisons.

```r
df1
         ColName1 ColName2 ColName3
RowName1        3        0        5
Rowname2        0        1        7
Rowname3        0        2        2
Rowname4        9        3        4

df2
         ColName1 ColName2
RowName3        A        Q
Rowname2        A        W
Rowname4        B        Q
Rowname1        B        W
```

I expect to get

```r
df2
             ColName1 ColName2
    RowName1        B        W
    Rowname2        A        W
    Rowname3        A        Q
    Rowname4        B        Q
```

I have seen post no. [27362718](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362718/) and tried the below, but it hasn't worked.

```
df2[order(match(rownames(df2), rownames(df1))), ]
```

This lists order indicating which rows does not match:

```
match(rownames(df2), rownames(df1))
```

This lists order but the rest does not set the order:

```
order(match(rownames(df2), rownames(df1)))
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible exampel with expected output. thanks

Comment: *"but it haven't worked"* - please be more specific. Did you get an error? A warning? A completely wrong result? A result that was mostly correct but had some issues?

Comment: Though, the example you are following is using a column, not row names. Since you actually have row names, you can probably use `df2[rownames(df1), ]`

Comment: I did not get any error message. The code was done but when I check if the order is the same with all(rownames(df1) == rownames(df2)) it returns FALSE. Both dataframes have the same number of rows

Comment: Thanks Gregor! the `df2[rownames(df1), ]` works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rownames to subset a matrix or data frame:

```
df2[rownames(df1), ]
```