# How to get correct order of tip labels in APE after calling ladderize function

Tags: r, phylogeny

I'm trying to order the rows of a dataframe based on the tip labels found in a phylogenetic tree. The way I was going to do this was to use the `match` function similar to the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977102/order-a-data-frames-rows-according-to-a-target-vector-that-specifies-the-desire), however I'm stuck cause the `tip.label` property of the `ape` phylo object doesn't change if you reorder the nodes using the `ladderize` function.

```
library(ape)
tree <- read.tree(text = "(((A,B),(C,D)),E);")
tree2 <- ladderize(tree, right = FALSE)
tree$tip.label
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
tree2$tip.label
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Notice that the order of the `tip.label` hasn't changed even though the visual representation of the tree does. In this simple example the visual order of the tree after the `ladderize` function is `E A B C D` (reading from bottom to top on the tree after plotting). How can I get a copy of the `tip.label` vector where the order reflects the new order of the nodes in the tree?

Answer (score 19):

It seems the key is to look at the `edge` property. The tips are always the first nodes to be given an ID, which will simply correspond to the position in the `tip.label` vector.

```
library(ape)
tree <- read.tree(text = "(((A,B),(C,D)),E);")
tree2 <- ladderize(tree, right = FALSE)
tree$tip.label
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
tree2$tip.label
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
plot(tree2)
nodelabels()
tiplabels()
```

First step is to filter out internal nodes from the the second column of the edge matrix:

```
is_tip <- tree2$edge[,2] <= length(tree2$tip.label)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

ordered_tips <- tree2$edge[is_tip, 2]
#> [1] 5 1 2 3 4
```

Then you can use this vector to extract the tips in the right order:

```
tree2$tip.label[ordered_tips]
#> [1] "E" "A" "B" "C" "D"
```