# extract two columns from dataframe and make into a vector

Tags: r, ape

I have a table with 4 columns, I want to extract column 1 and 3 to make a character vector. My aim is to define colour for a phylogenetic plot

```
Table
name    id  colour  date    
t1  a   red 10/01
t2  b   red 09/02       
t3  c   black   04/04
t4  d   black   05/05

Desired vector
cols <- c("t1"="red", "t2"="red", "t3"="black", "t4"="black")
```

Ive tried the suggestion from here but Its not giving me what I want.
[Converting two columns of a data frame to a named vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265172/converting-two-columns-of-a-data-frame-to-a-named-vector)

When I execute my command to plot the phylogeny the colour matrix provided in the vector does not comply. The colours do not match what I have in the table.

For more info see [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006500/r-coloured-lines-for-tangelgram-package-ape-function-cophyloplot)
I want to colour the lines in a tanglegram using [cophyloplot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ape/versions/4.1/topics/cophyloplot) in ape. Argument `"col=" states a character vector indicating the color to be used for the links; recycled as necessary`

Comment: @Cath Ive added more info. Basically when I go to plot my phylogeny the colours in the vector do not work.

Comment: @Cath interger. I assume my next move is to convert this to character? Im not a wizz on R Im afraid. But would as.character be necessary?

Comment: Ah cool. Ive tried several workflows including an ordered vector but no joy. My actual phylo is much bigger (92 taxa) and something must be going wrong in the execution. Thanks for the help Cath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setNames` function, for instance:

```
setNames(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Species)
```