# Combine dendrogram with bipartite graphs in R (tanglegram)

Tags: r, dendrogram, vegan, bipartite, phylogeny

I am currently working on creating a tanglegram where species reared are on one side and substrate reared on is on the other side. However, I need the output to also be a tanglegram, having each side of the chart be the tips of a dendogram. I currently have phylogenies of both the species and substrates in Newick formats.

I successfully used the ['ape'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364660/how-to-get-correct-order-of-tip-labels-in-ape-after-calling-ladderize-function) package and the `plot.phylo()` function to generate the 2 phylogenies. I then used the following code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364660/how-to-get-correct-order-of-tip-labels-in-ape-after-calling-ladderize-function) to export the order of tips:

```
tree <- ladderize(tree, right = FALSE)
is_tip <- tree$edge[,2] <= length(tree$tip.label)
ordered_tips <- tree$edge[is_tip, 2]
x<-tree$tip.label[ordered_tips]
write.csv(x,file="test.csv",sep ="\t")
```

I then used the order of the tips to generate a matrix for use in the ['bipartite'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bipartite/bipartite.pdf) package.

However, of course, the spacing on the bipartite graph doesn't match up with the spacing on the dengdrograms, so I can't just copy/paste them next to one another in an outside image manipulation program. I am wondering if there is a way that I can generate a chart that combines the dendrograms and bipartite graph to make a tanglegram in rstudio?

Here is a simplified visual example of what I am hoping to do:

I am looking to combine 2 phylogenetic trees that, for example, look like this

```
tree1<-read.tree(text="((C,B),A);")
plot(tree1)
```

Output: [tree1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ModaE.png)

```
tree2<-read.tree(text="((G,F),(E,D));")
plot(tree2)
```

Output: [tree2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaB6N.png)

With a bipartite graph

```
web = matrix(
c(0, 5, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1),
nrow=4,
ncol=3,
byrow = TRUE,
dimnames = list(c("D","E","F","G"),c("A","B","C"))) 
plotweb(web,method="normal",empty="false",text.rot="90")
```

Output: [bipartite plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ngXY.png)

To instead generate a plot that looks like this (I just did the following in an image editor, the expansive dataset I am actually using is far larger)

Desired output: [tanglegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8WPM.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to draw a tanglegram with trees where the tip labels do not match is to use an association matrix - a matrix that lists corresponding taxa in the respective trees. Using the provided data, the following code will extract the names from columns and rows and the respective weight.

```
 assoc = data.frame()
 temp = matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = ncol(web))

 for(i in 1:nrow(web)){
     for(j in 1:ncol(web)){
         temp[j,] = c(rownames(web)[i], colnames(web)[j], web[i,j])
     }
     assoc = rbind(assoc, temp)
 }
head(assoc)
  V1 V2 V3
 1  D  A  0
 2  D  B  5
 3  D  C  0
 4  E  A 10
 5  E  B 10
```

The last column can be used to set weight of the connecting lines between taxa.

```
library(ape)
cophyloplot(tree2, tree1, assoc[,1:2], lwd = as.numeric(as.character(assoc[,3])), space = 15)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! Beautiful job! That's very nice.

For my actual dataset I ended up needing to add these two lines as well
`tree1<-collapse.singles(tree1)`
`tree2<-collapse.singles(tree2)`

I didn't need to in this case, but [this reference](https://bitsaying.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/tired-of-what-apes-collapse-singles-does-heres-a-way-to-put-those-nodes-back/) might be useful for others if they are trying to conserve branch lengths after collapsing singles

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `cophylo` from the [`phytools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phytools/index.html) package:

```
require(phytools)
## Your two trees
tree1 <- ape::rcoal(10)
tree2 <- ape::rcoal(10)
```

If both trees have matching tip labels, you can pass them to the `cophylo` functions in `phytools` to create a `"cophylo"` object:

```
## Creating the tanglegram
tanglegram <- phytools::cophylo(tree1, tree2)
# Rotating nodes to optimize matching...
# Done.
```

And plotting using the S3 `"cophylo"` method:

```
## Plotting the tanglegram
plot(tanglegram)
```

Have a look at this excellent [blog post](http://blog.phytools.org/2018/06/preserving-node-edge-labels-after.html) containing more details on how to use these `"cophylo"` objects.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your response and for the blog post! My problem is that I am trying to pass through 2 trees with different tip labels (one tree of species reared and one tree of substrates these species were reared on).

I edited my post to include images for you that might show what I am trying to accomplish better than I could explain.