# How to order a column within a group in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Class" = c('Class 8','Class 9','Class 10','Class 8','Class 9','Class 10','Class 8','Class 9','Class 10'),
  "Status" = c('Good','Good','Good','Better','Better','Better','Best','Best','Best'),
  "Percentage" = c(4,4,6,14,13,15,83,81,78),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I am having a vector describing the order of Status within each group.

```
ratingOrder <<- c('Good','Better','Best')
```

I am trying to arrange the Status for each Class as given in the vector.

This is the expected output

```
     Class Status Percentage
1  Class 8   Good          4
2  Class 8 Better          4
3  Class 8   Best          6
4  Class 9   Good         14
5  Class 9 Better         13
6  Class 9   Best         15
7  Class 10  Good         83
8  Class 10 Better         81
9  Class 10  Best         78
```

Can anyone give a suitable solution to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `factor` column to take the order into account. Another thing you need to solve is the *Class* column that needs to be `numeric` in order to be sorted numerically.

Here is a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Status = factor(Status, levels = ratingOrder),
         Class = as.numeric(gsub("Class ", "", Class))) %>%
  arrange(Class, Status)
```

Output:

```
  Class Status Percentage
1     8   Good          4
2     8 Better         14
3     8   Best         83
4     9   Good          4
5     9 Better         13
6     9   Best         81
7    10   Good          6
8    10 Better         15
9    10   Best         78
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Status = factor(Status, levels = ratingOrder),
         Class = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", Class))) %>%
  arrange(Class, Status)
```

The `match` function is used to create on-the-fly a numeric vector resembling the order of `ratingOrder` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977102/order-data-frame-rows-according-to-vector-with-specific-order) post for reference).

Output

```
#      Class Status Percentage
# 1  Class 8   Good          4
# 2  Class 8 Better         14
# 3  Class 8   Best         83
# 4  Class 9   Good          4
# 5  Class 9 Better         13
# 6  Class 9   Best         81
# 7 Class 10   Good          6
# 8 Class 10 Better         15
# 9 Class 10   Best         78
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option:

```
df$Status <- factor(df$Status, levels = ratingOrder) 
df$Class <- factor(df$Class, levels = paste("Class", 8:10))

df[order(df$Class, df$Status), ]

     Class Status Percentage
1  Class 8   Good          4
4  Class 8 Better         14
7  Class 8   Best         83
2  Class 9   Good          4
5  Class 9 Better         13
8  Class 9   Best         81
3 Class 10   Good          6
6 Class 10 Better         15
9 Class 10   Best         78
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some `dplyr` solutions but I want to propose:

```r
df %>%
  arrange(as.integer(str_extract(Class, "\\d+")), match(Status, ratingOrder))
```

which also yields

```r
     Class Status Percentage
1  Class 8   Good          4
2  Class 8 Better         14
3  Class 8   Best         83
4  Class 9   Good          4
5  Class 9 Better         13
6  Class 9   Best         81
7 Class 10   Good          6
8 Class 10 Better         15
9 Class 10   Best         78
```