# How do I change the order of factor levels printed for kable()?

Tags: r, tidyverse, knitr, forcats

in my desired output, the result for red would be printed before the result for green. Specifically, how to a change the order of factor levels for printing in a kable (or similar) table?

```
var1<-sample(c("red", "green"), 100, replace=T)
var2<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)

library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
df %>% 
  group_by(var1) %>% 
  summarize(avg=mean(var2)) %>% 
  mutate(var1=fct_relevel(var1, "red", "green")) %>% 
  kable()
```

Comment: `...arrange(match(c('red', 'green'), var1)) %>%...` ? See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977102/order-data-frame-rows-according-to-vector-with-specific-order

Comment: This looks good, but this all seems unwieldy, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `arrange` to sort your dataframe by your `var1`

```r
var1<-sample(c("red", "green"), 100, replace=T)
var2<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)

library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
df %>% 
  group_by(var1) %>% 
  summarize(avg=mean(var2)) %>% 
  mutate(var1=fct_relevel(var1, "red", "green")) %>% 
  arrange(var1) %>% # Arranges the data frame by this variable
  kable()

|var1  |        avg|
|:-----|----------:|
|red   |  0.0999524|
|green | -0.0378017|
```

Comment: This won't work as there is my specific case requires ordering the factor levels by some non-numeric quantity. This seems like a limitation of kable.

Comment: In that case you are better served with the answer provided in the question linked by @Ronak Shah

Comment: No, this will work, actually. The arrange() function actually orders the data frame in the order of the factor levels set in the `mutate(fct_relevel)` command. It works just great. I prefer this answer because it is wholly based in the `tidyverse` Thank you.