# How to sort dataframe by column header which is a mix of text and numbers

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data frame which looks like the following

```
   GR1-text GR11-text GR12-text GR2-text
A    1          1       0          0
B    1          0       1          1
```

I want to sort the dataframe to look like:

```
   GR1-text  GR2-text  GR11-text  GR12-test
A   1         0         1           0
B   1         1         0           1
```

I have tried the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334644/sort-columns-of-a-dataframe-by-column-name) which has not worked

```
test <- df[ , order(names(df))]
```

Ive also spotted this [custom function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13117/how-to-sort-a-character-vector-numerically-based-on-a-trailing-digit-in-r?rq=1) but I cannot seen to get it to work.

Comment: Is `GR-12-text` a typo?

Comment: it is sorry. Ill change it now. Thanks

Comment: `library(gtools);
df[, mixedsort(names(df))]`

Comment: @RonakShah This works. Thanks a mill. Do you want to put down the answer below?

Comment: @AudileF Actually this question has been asked before already and hence, it is marked as duplicate of those previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `order(readr::parse_number(names(df)))`.

Comment: Thanks for this @F.Prive. but I get an error `Warning: 43 parsing failures.
row # A tibble: 5 x 4 col     row   col expected actual expected   <int> <int>    <chr>  <chr> actual 1    82    NA a number      - row 2    83    NA a number      - col 3    84    NA a number      - expected 4    85    NA a number      - actual 5    86    NA a number      -
... ........
See problems(...) for more details.`

Comment: Can you provide all the names? Or put the `parse_number()` result in a variable and see the problems with `problems()`.