# Sort columns of a dataframe by column name as Date

Tags: r, sorting, date, dataframe

Similar issue is handled in the question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334644/sort-columns-of-a-dataframe-by-column-name)
I have the data frame with dates as column name.

```
test = data.frame("01-Apr-16" = c(0, 2, 4, 7, 8), 
                  "01-Jan-16" = c(4, 2, 4, 7, 8), 
                  "01-Dec-16" = c(1, 3, 8, 3, 2))
```

I have converted the dates to corresponding number formats

```
new_names = apply(data.frame(names(test)), 1, function(x) as.Date(strptime(x,format = "%d-%b-%y")))
colnames(test) = new_names
```

The solution provided `test[ , order(names(test))]` doesn't works. 
Is there a efficient solution to the problem.

I have read the dataframe from an external .csv file, which retains the original format of dates in the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `apply`,

```
i1 <- as.Date(names(test), format = 'X%d.%b.%y')
test[order(i1)]
```

which gives,

> ```
>   X01.Jan.16 X01.Apr.16 X01.Dec.16
> 1          4          0          1
> 2          2          2          3
> 3          4          4          8
> 4          7          7          3
> 5          8          8          2
> ```