# merge data frames reordering columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames (x, y) with same column names. For example, FIRST, NAME1, NAME2, NAME3. I need to merge them by "FIRST" column, but reorder other columns like this: FIRST, NAME1.x, NAME1.y, NAME2.x, NAME2.y, etc.

```
x
FIRST   NAME1   NAME2   NAME3
q1  xxx xxx xxx
q2  xxx xxx xxx
q3  xxx xxx xxx
q4  xxx xxx xxx

y
FIRST   NAME1   NAME2   NAME3
  q1    yyy yyy yyy
  q2    yyy yyy yyy
  q3    yyy yyy yyy
  q4    yyy yyy yyy
```

If I create new data frame like this:

```
df = merge(x,y, by = "FIRST")
```

I get

```
FIRST   NAME1.x NAME2.x NAME3.x NAME1.y NAME2.y NAME3.y
   q1   xxx      xxx     xxx     yyy     yyy    yyy
   q2   xxx      xxx     xxx     yyy     yyy    yyy
   q3   xxx      xxx     xxx     yyy     yyy    yyy
   q4   xxx      xxx     xxx     yyy     yyy    yyy
```

But I want to have the next result:

```
FIRST   NAME1.x NAME1.y NAME2.x NAME2.y NAME3.x NAME3.y
  q1    xxx      yyy     xxx     yyy     xxx    yyy
  q2    xxx      yyy     xxx     yyy     xxx    yyy
  q3    xxx      yyy     xxx     yyy     xxx    yyy
  q4    xxx      yyy     xxx     yyy     xxx    yyy
```

Just reordering columns isn't the solution, because in future there will always be x and y with different number of columns.

Comment: Would this be useful for you: `df[, sort(names(df))]` ?

Comment: Do the columns in `x` and `y` have prefixes that you could order them by? I don't think there's a join procedure that would automatically interleave the columns.

Comment: Most probably comment by @markus should solve your question which is also mentioned in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334644/sort-columns-of-a-dataframe-by-column-name

Comment: @markus, this work. Good decision! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to reorder the columns after merging them:

```
df = merge(x,y, by = "FIRST")
df <- data.frame(FIRST = df$FIRST,
                 NAME1.x = df$NAME1.x,
                 NAME1.y = df$NAME1.y, 
                 NAME2.x = df$NAME2.x,
                 NAME2.y = df$NAME2.y, 
                 NAME3.x = df$NAME3.x,
                 NAME3.y = df$NAME3.y)
```

So you can put the columns in the place you want, with the names you desire.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dplyr` functions `left_join(df1, df2, by = 'FIRST')` then use

```
%>%
select(FIRST, NAME1.x, NAME1.y, NAME2.x, NAME2.y, NAME3.x, NAME3.y)
```

to reorder. The pipe allows it to happy in one step.